# How to get original machine Created Date for file after uploaded to Google Drive (seems to be overwritten by uploader+Google with time of upload)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

- I upload a lot of logs to Google Drive folder for merging
- I expect the created and modified date to remain intact since I did not recreate or modify these files
- I use a Google Script to analyze the logs in this drive folder and put the data into a Google Sheet for logviewing and analysis

Two problems:

- If the log entries have only UTC timestamps, then I can't find the UTC offset of the machine that created it, since I do not know file creation time (usually I would subtract first log entry with file creation time to get the hour differential)
- One of the log types uses amount of ticks after log file creation instead of timestamps. The creation time is written in first entry. Problematic though since this format is based on locale so its difficult to parse. Even the clock can be PM or 24H

getDateCreated() and getLastUpdated() for DriveApp seem to be overwritten by uploader and time of upload:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file

Is there any way to get this original creation date after having uploaded the logs to Google Drive (I would like to avoid using rclone etc to make it easy for users)?

--- **Example script**

- Create a new text file in Notepad and save it as sample_log.txt with some content.
- Upload the sample_log.txt file to a Google Drive folder.
- Create a Google Apps Script that accesses the uploaded file and displays its Date Created and Last Updated timestamps:

```
function testFileTimestamps() {
  // Replace 'Folder ID' with the actual ID of your Google Drive folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID');
  
  // Replace 'File Name' with the actual name of your uploaded file
  var file = folder.getFilesByName('sample_log.txt').next();
  
  var dateCreated = file.getDateCreated();
  var lastUpdated = file.getLastUpdated();
  
  Logger.log('Date Created: ' + dateCreated);
  Logger.log('Last Updated: ' + lastUpdated);
}
```

Here's how you can use the script:

- Open your Google Apps Script project.
- Paste the above script into the script editor.
- Replace 'Folder ID' with the actual ID of your Google Drive folder.
- Replace 'File Name' with the actual name of your uploaded sample_log.txt file.
- Save the script and run the testFileTimestamps function.

When you run the testFileTimestamps function, it will retrieve the Date Created and Last Updated timestamps for the specified file in your Google Drive folder and log the results in the Google Apps Script editor's logging console. The timestamps displayed will likely reflect the upload time rather than the original creation/saving time in Notepad.

[image: File created date is changedby Google to be time of upload, not time of creation]

--- **SUMMARY**

In very simple terms: How can I get the original file created time using Google Script?:
[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Is there any way to get this original creation date after having uploaded the logs to Google Drive (I would like to avoid using rclone etc to make it easy for users)?`. Can you provide your current script? And, can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Expected: getDateCreated() to get the date from when the .log was created by a local machine

Comment: Actual: getDateCreated() gets the date from when the .log was uploaded to Google Drive

Comment: This means the Initial Creation Date of the .log file has been changed and can therefore not be used to calculate UTC to Local Time conversion (for example +2 hours difference). It also means I cannot use logs with the format "ticks since log file creation", since I have to calculate those. You can see the date format here, but it is different for each machine locale (not ideal), hard to parse accurately: https://www.scribd.com/document/558864101/Adobe-Media-Encoder-Log

Comment: @Tanaike I have provided an example script

Comment: I do apologize with this. Please narrow down your questions, and please clarify more about your use cases and instances about "If the log entries have only UTC timestamps, then I can't find the UTC offset of the machine that created it, since I do not know file creation time (usually I would subtract first log entry with file creation time to get the hour differential)" I do understand that you want to get your Time Created date, I don't understand on the part that to receive it right away.

Comment: Please see updated screenshot. Hopefully this explains the issue? 02:23:00 vs 02:23:22 (I uploaded `Create file.txt` to Google Drive, 22 seconds after using Save As in notepad). I cannot use modified date, but it seems more intact.

Comment: Yes, it is actually kind of expected behaviour on File Systems. Original creation date Metadata is not being kept by default, copied data changes its Original Creation date depending on when it was existent on the drive. Moreover it is actually a feature idea on the part of the File Systems and lengthy discussion has been dedicated over this, I don't know your exact use case, but I might probably look for alternative path for this one if the creation date is really important, last modified on the other hand actually passed the meta data fairly as expected depending on the file types.

Comment: You can start here on this article you might find some work around that might not directly with Google Apps Script, but using local machines capabilities. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253552982